# Spring Web Application Returning 405 error on PUT Call

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a Java Spring web application that creates a list of roles that can be assigned to users. However, I am having an issue creating new roles which is invoked through an AJAX PUT call that returns a 405 error. The application is running on Java 8 and Spring 5.1.1.

I have tried debugging both the front end and back end side. What I found was, the call successfully reaches the back-end, processes the call through and returns. However, the front-end will claim that an error occurred and returns a 405 error. But the issue is, the error does not provide any details on what is failing exactly. The most information I could find was this message:

```
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)
    at Object.error (http://localhost:8000/xxx/admin-user-search.html:1011:10)
    at fire (http://localhost:8000/xxxx/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js:3305:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:8000/xxxx/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js:3435:7)
    at done (http://localhost:8000/xxxx/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js:9244:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/xxxx/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js:9484:9)
```

Javascript:

```
function submitCreateNewRole(){
    isBlank = false;  
    var myData;

     newRoleName = $('#modalUserRoleSearchText').val();
     newRoleDescription = $('#modelUserRoleDescText').val();

     if (newRoleName=='' || newRoleDescription==''){
         isBlank = true;
     }

     if (isBlank){
         appAPI.setErrorBannerRole("Blank data is not allowed. Please enter non-blank data to create new Role.");
     } else {
         var UserRoleSearchModel = {}; 
         var userRoleAction = "createNewUserRole" ;

         RoleModel.ldapName = newRoleName; 
         RoleModel.roleDesc = newRoleDescription;      
         var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
         var URL = "json/admin-user-search?userRoleAction=" + userRoleAction + "&roleName=" + newRoleName + "&roleDesc=" + newRoleDescription;
         var req = JSON.stringify(RoleModel);
         var jqxhr = $.ajax({               
             type: "PUT",
             url: URL,
             headers: { "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : token },
             data: req,
             contentType: "application/json",
             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                 console.log("Failure caught");
                 console.log(xhr.responseText);
             },
             success: function(data){
                 myData = data;
             }
         }).done(function( msg ) {
             $('#alertMessageSuccess').val('Successfully create new row');
          }).fail(function(jqxhr) {
          $('#alertMessageError').val('failed to create role' + newRoleName);   
          });
      }  

      return myData; 
 }
```

Java Spring:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {
      "admin-user-search"
  }, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  public ModelAndView createNewUserRole(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal,
      @RequestParam(required = false) String pageCommand,
      @ModelAttribute("UserModel") UserModel userSearch,
      @ModelAttribute("RoleModel") RoleModel userRoleSearch,
      @RequestParam(value = "roleName", required = false) String roleName,
      @RequestParam(value = "roleDesc", required = false) String roleDesc,
      @RequestParam(value = "userRoleAction", required = false) String userRoleCommmand, HttpServletRequest request) {

    Results results = null;
    List<Role> roleVOs = null;
    String roleResponseMessage;

    ModelAndView rView = new ModelAndView("admin-user-search");

    if ("createNewUserRole".equals(userRoleCommmand)) {
      userRoleSearch.clearAlertMessages();
      userSearch.clearAlertMessage();

      if ("".equals(roleName)) {
        roleResponseMessage = "Unable to create a new role due to invalid or blank LDAP username enterred. Please try again with valid LDAP username.";
        userRoleSearch.setErrorMessages(roleResponseMessage);
      } else if ("".equals(roleDesc)) {
        roleResponseMessage = "Unable to create a new role due to invalid or blank Role Description entered.";
        userRoleSearch.setErrorMessages(roleResponseMessage);
      } else {
        try {
          this.tdmcRoleDao.addNewRole(roleName, roleDesc);
          roleResponseMessage = String.format("New user role '%s' has been added.", userRoleSearch.getLdapDn());
          userRoleSearch.setSuccessMessages(roleResponseMessage);
          userSearch.setSuccessMessages(roleResponseMessage);

          roleVOs = retrieveAllRoles();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
          LOGGER.error(e, TDMCMessages.TDMC_0142_DATABASE_INSERT_EXCEPTION, "tdmcRoleDao.addNewRole(newRoleLdap)");
          roleResponseMessage = "Unable to create a new role -'%s' due to DB problem. Please retry with a new  valid role name.";
          userRoleSearch.setErrorMessages(roleResponseMessage);
          userSearch.setErrorMessages(roleResponseMessage);
        } catch (final DuplicateKeyException dupEx) {
          roleResponseMessage = "Unable to create a duplicate role'. Please retry with non-duplicated role name.";
          userRoleSearch.setErrorMessages(roleResponseMessage);
          userSearch.setErrorMessages(roleResponseMessage);
        }

        if (roleVOs != null && !roleVOs.isEmpty()) {
            results = populateRolesToResults(roleVOs);
        }

        userRoleSearch.setResults(results);
        userRoleSearch.setSelected(roleVOs);

        rView.addObject("RoleModel", userRoleSearch);
      }
    }

    return rView;
}
```

When I run the application and try to create a new Role, I see that the PUT call reaches the Java server and successfully returns the view. However, on the Web client side, it throws the 405 error, and it's not clear what exactly is failing. Any insight would be very helpful.

On another note, the application also makes POST and GET calls as well, but those seem to work fine, so I cannot understand why the PUT calls are failing in this case.

EDIT: Fix code

Answer (score 0):

first of all your url seems to be wrong, please check.
and change to post mapping, then post through body, something 
like @requesrbody

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean? What seems to be wrong with the url? And would do you mean by requesrbody?

Comment: change url as /admin-user-search

Comment: update controller method for post mapping, make a poco for role object, and handle this request from @requestbody